# Is there a definitive list of what gifts a companion likes?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

Is there any resource to tell you exactly which gifts are a waste of time and which ones are going to result in maximum gain?

Comment: Most of the answers to this question are out of date.  A new (up to date) answer has been posted to help people with the new companions.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's the [full list](http://www.darthhater.com/articles/feature/19836-guide-companion-gifts). Gift level must be equal to or greater than the current affection level of your companion to yield the full bonus. For every level higher your companion is relative to the gift, the bonus they receive from it is halved. Green colored gifts yield the amount of affection shown below. Blue yield 50% more. I believe but am not certain that purple gifts yield 100% more.

- Favorite: +96 affection
- Love: +54 affection
- Like: +24 affection

Courting gifts only work for companions of the opposite sex.

Note that, short of someone posting on the auction house for way under price, it isn't cost effective to give your companion higher level gifts than they need, since it won't give them more affection than an equal-level gift. In fact, it's often more cost effective (if buying from vendors) to give them 2 gifts one level lower than their affection level than to give them one of the appropriate level.

> ## Imperial

### Bounty Hunter

- **Blizz**

  - Favorite - *Technology, Underworld Goods*.
  - Love - *Cultural Artifact, Imperial Memorabilia, Luxury, Military Gear, Republic Memorabilia, Trophy, Weapon.*
  - Like - *None*.
- **Gault**:

  - Favorite - *Luxury*.
  - Love - *Underworld Goods.*
  - Like - *Cultural Artifact, Technology, Weapon.*
- **Mako**:

  - Favorite - *Technology*.
  - Love - *Underworld Goods*.
  - Like - *Cultural Artifact, Luxury, Trophy, Weapon.*
- **Skadge**:

  - Favorite - *Underworld Goods, Weapon.*
  - Love - *None*.
  - Like - *Luxury, Military Gear, Trophy.*
- **Torian Cadera**:

  - Favorite - *Trophy*.
  - Love - *Courting, Military Gear, Weapon*.
  - Like - *Cultural Artifact, Technology, Underworld Goods*.

### Imperial Agent

- **Doctor Lokin**:

  - Favorite - *Technology*.
  - Love - *Luxury, Military Gear*.
  - Like - *Imperial Memorabilia, Republic Memorabilia, Underworld Goods.*
- **Ensign Raina Temple**:

  - Favorite - *Imperial Memorabilia.*
  - Love - *Military
    Gear*.
  - Like - *Courting, Luxury, Republic Memorabilia, Weapon.*
- **Kaliyo Djannis**:

  - Favorite - *Weapon.*
  - Love - *Luxury, Underworld Goods.*
  - Like - *Military Gear, Technology.*
- **Scorpio**:

  - Favorite - *Technology.*
  - Love - *Weapon*.
  - Like - *Cultural Artifact, Military Gear, Trophy.*
- **Vector**:

  - Favorite - *Cultural Artifact*.
  - Love - *Imperial Memorabilia.*
  - Like - *Courting, Luxury, Trophy, Weapon.*

### Sith Inquisitor

- **Andronikos Revel**:

  - Favorite - *Weapon*.
  - Love - *Military Gear, Underworld
    Goods*.
  - Like - *Courting, Luxury.*
- **Ashara Zavros**:

  - Favorite - *Military Gear, Weapon.*
  - Love - *Courting,
    Republic Memorabilia.*
  - Like - *Cultural Artifact, Luxury, Underworld
    Goods.*
- **Khem Val**:

  - Favorite - *Cultural Artifact*.
  - Love - *Weapon*.
  - Like -
    *Imperial Memorabilia, Technology, Trophy.*
- **Talos Drellik**:

  - Favorite - *Cultural Artifact.*
  - Love - *Luxury, Imperial
    Memorabilia, Republic Memorabilia.*
  - Like - *Courting, Technology.*
- **Xalek**:

  - Favorite - *Military Gear, Weapon.*
  - Love - *None*.
  - Like - *Trophy,
    Underworld Goods.*

### Sith Warrior

- **Broonmark**:

  - Favorite - *Trophy, Weapon.*
  - Love - *Republic Memorabilia,
    Technology.*
  - Like - *Cultural Artifact, Military Gear, Imperial
    Memorabilia.*
- **Jaesa Willsaam Dark**:

  - Favorite - *Weapon*.
  - Love - *Luxury, Trophy.*
  - Like -
    *Imperial Memorabilia, Military Gear.*
- **Jaesa Willsaam Light**:

  - Favorite - *Cultural Artifact, Republic
    Memorabilia.*
  - Love - *None*.
  - Like - *Courting, Military Gear, Trophy.*
- **Lieutenant Pierce**:

  - Favorite - *Military Gear, Weapon*.
  - Love - *None*.
  - Like - *Courting, Imperial Memorabilia, Republic Memorabilia,
    Technology, Trophy, Underworld Goods.*
- **Malavai Quinn**:

  - Favorite - *None*.
  - Love - *Imperial Memorabilia, Military
    Gear, Weapon*.
  - Like - *Courting, Technology, Trophy*.
- **Vette**:

  - Favorite - *Underworld Goods.*
  - Love - *Cultural Artifact, Weapon*.
  - Like - *Courting, Luxury, Imperial Memorabilia, Republic Memorabilia,
    Technology, Weapon.*

> ## Republic

### Jedi Consular

- **Lieutenant Iresso**:

  - Favorite - *Trophy*.
  - Love - *Republic Memorabilia.*
  - Like - *Courting, Luxury, Weapon.*
- **Nadia Grell**:

  - Favorite - *Cultural Artifact.*
  - Love - *Republic
    Memorabilia*.
  - Like - *Courting, Luxury, Underworld Goods.*
- **Qyzen Fess**:

  - Favorite - *Weapon.*
  - Love - *Military Gear*.
  - Like -
    *Technology, Underworld Goods.*
- **Tharan Cedrax**:

  - Favorite - *Luxury*.
  - Love - *Technology*.
  - Like - *Courting,
    Cultural Artifact, Underworld Goods.*
- **Zenith**:

  - Favorite - *Imperial Memorabilia.*
  - Love - *Weapon*.
  - Like -
    *Military Gear, Underworld Goods.*

### Jedi Knight

- **Doc**:

  - Favorite - *None*.
  - Love - *Courting, Luxury.*
  - Like - *Cultural
    Artifact, Military Gear, Technology, Trophy, Underworld Goods,
    Weapon.*
- **Kira Carsen**:

  - Favorite - *None*.
  - Love - *Luxury, Technology.*
  - Like -
    *Military Gear, Imperial Memorabilia, Republic Memorabilia, Trophy,
    Underworld Goods.*
- **Lord Scourge**:

  - Favorite - *Trophy*.
  - Love - *Imperial Memorabilia,
    Technology*.
  - Like - *Cultural Artifact, Military Gear, Republic
    Memorabilia, Underworld Goods, Weapon.*
- **Sergeant Rusk**:

  - Favorite - *Military Gear.*
  - Love - *Republic Memorabilia,
    Weapon.*
  - Like - *Cultural Artifact, Imperial Memorabilia, Luxury,
    Trophy.*
- **T7-01**:

  - Favorite - *Technology.*
  - Love - *Cultural Artifact, Republic
    Memorabilia.*
  - Like - *Weapon*.

### Smuggler

- **Akaavi Spar**:

  - Favorite - *Weapon*.
  - Love - *Military Gear, Trophy.*
  - Like - *Courting, Imperial Memorabilia, Republic Memorabilia, Technology,
    Underworld Goods.*
- **Bowdaar**:

  - Favorite - *Cultural Artifact, Luxury.*
  - Love - *Weapon, Trophy.*
  - Like - *Military Gear, Technology, Underworld Goods.*
- **Corso Riggs**:

  - Favorite - *Weapon*.
  - Love - *Military Gear*.
  - Like - *Courting, Cultural Artifact, Luxury, Technology.*
- **Guss Tuno**:

  - Favorite - *Underworld Goods.*
  - Love - *Luxury, Technology.*
  - Like - *Courting, Cultural Artifact, Imperial Memorabilia, Republic
    Memorabilia, Trophy.*
- **Risha**:

  - Favorite - *None*.
  - Love - *Cultural Artifact, Luxury, Underworld
    Goods.*
  - Like - *Courting, Imperial Memorabilia, Military Gear, Republic
    Memorabilia, Weapon.*

### Trooper

- **Aric Jorgan**:

  - Favorite -  *Weapon*.
  - Love - *Military Gear*.
  - Like - *Courting, Cultural Artifact, Republic Memorabilia, Technology, Trophy.*
- **Elara Dorne**:

  - Favorite - *Luxury*.
  - Love - *None*.
  - Like - *Courting, Imperial Memorabilia, Military Gear, Republic Memorabilia,
    Technology*.
- **M1-4X**:

  - Favorite - *Republic Memorabilia*.
  - Love - *Technology*.
  - Like - *Cultural Artifact, Military Gear, Trophy, Weapon*.
- **Tanno Vik**:

  - Favorite - *Underworld Goods*.
  - Love - *Weapon*.
  - Like - *Military Gear, Trophy*.
- **Yuun**:

  - Favorite - *Cultural Artifact, Technology, Trophy*.
  - Love - *None*.
  - Like - *Imperial Memorabilia, Military Gear, Republic Memorabilia, Weapon.*

Comment: You're missing C2-N2 for Jedi Knight.

Comment: Hmm, [apparently he's not a "true" companion](http://www.swtor.com/community/showthread.php?t=51848).  Nevermind.  I need to stop using him for missions :P

Comment: If you copy and paste this from a source (http://www.darthhater.com/articles/feature/19836-guide-companion-gifts), you should give credit to them.

Answer (score 5):

This has already been answered successfully, but these images from:

http://www.oldrepublic.net/261-swtor-companion-gifts-guide-how-buy-your-love.html

Is definitely the best layout I've seen. It's extra nice as it helps you determine easily who you can trade specific gifts you are stocking piling to (alts, guildmates, etc.).

[image]

[image]

Comment: Looks nice! I like this much better than my own answer for it.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.swtor-spy.com/companions/

Click on any companion, you'll have the details.

Comment: Hey, Freddy - would you mind copying the relevant bits into your answer here? It helps to keep the information on gaming, and makes headroads into the war against link decay! (Basically, as is, your answer is null'd if the link ever goes dead :/ )

Answer (score 1):

[Darth Hater's Guide: Companion Gifts](http://www.darthhater.com/articles/feature/19836-guide-companion-gifts) is my favorite as it lists them all in one page, highlighted with colors to improve readability.

You can also go to your in-game Codex (go to your Mission Log and click the Codex tab at the center bottom of the window) where the Person's Of Note section will have an entry for each of your companions. They list there conversation choice preferences, but only sometimes hint at gifts. The above guide is more explicit with exactly which ones work and how much relative to each other.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question but still a very relevant one to the game, unfortunately all of the answers are incomplete(due to the game adding or changing companions) or have invalid links.
For this reason i am adding a new answer with a new source; http://dulfy.net/

In this article on the site you can find a lot of info on how companion affection works in the game after the 4.0 update.

- [Complete companion influence article](http://dulfy.net/2015/10/21/swtor-fallen-empire-companion-influences-guide/)

The following 2 pictures will show affection gain for the '*classic*' companions.
All the new companions and their interest are listed in the article and are currently up to date.

- [Recruited via Alliance Specialists](http://dulfy.net/2015/10/21/swtor-fallen-empire-companion-influences-guide/#Recruited_via_Alliance_Specialists)
- [Recruited via Star Fortress](http://dulfy.net/2015/10/21/swtor-fallen-empire-companion-influences-guide/#Recruited_via_Star_Fortress)
- [Recruited via Cartel Market](http://dulfy.net/2015/10/21/swtor-fallen-empire-companion-influences-guide/#Recruited_via_Cartel_Market)
- [Recruited via KotFE story line](http://dulfy.net/2015/10/21/swtor-fallen-empire-companion-influences-guide/#Main_Characters)

[image: Empire]

[image: Republic]

There is also a sorted list per gift type:

- [Sorted by gift type](http://dulfy.net/2015/10/21/swtor-fallen-empire-companion-influences-guide/#Companions_Sorted_by_Gifts)